# is there a way to implement afterprint on jspdf after using its autoprint function?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

after the autoprint of jspdf, I want to call certain callback function when user prints or cancel, but I didn't find anyway to trigger afterprint on jspdf. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated, thank you.

I searched a lot on how to implement, even tried to exceute window.afterprint after the autoprint() function but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to have some orientation points.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.